# What is the running time of the following program?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The exercise in my book is asking me to calculate the running time of the following for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    ++k;
```

This instantly reminds me of summation notation. So I write down the appropriate syntax:

[image]

Is this correct? If not, why not - and how can I calculate it correctly?

Comment: All you are doing here is counting. If I understand your exercise statement, it has to do with measuring clock time. For that, you would need to use a high precision clock function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the operation inside the loop:

```
++k;
```

No matter what `k` is, that operation will take constant time. So let's replace it with `O(1)`.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    O(1)
```

We can see that we are going to iterate over the `O(1)` block `n` times. So that is:

```
O(n) * O(1)
```

Which is clearly equal to:

```
O(n)
```

Comment: In the book that I am following, we're not using the `O` syntax. We're breaking down equations that represent the code. So in this case it is like the summation notation in my question.

Comment: Perhaps your book is looking for `\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1`? But I can only help with the notation I know. If you'd like to read up on this notation, [here's the wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Your code is summing `1 + 1 + 1 + ...` `n` times. My code is adding `k + 1 + 1...` - `k` is not guaranteed to start at `1`.

Comment: How does the initial value of `k` change the time complexity of the code?

Comment: Doesn't it change the equation?

Comment: [Here's the page that I'm on in the book.](http://brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page51.html) See how he breaks down the equation? How did you break it down to `\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this correct?

No. It is not.

> If not, why not - and how can I calculate it correctly?

`k` is incremented by `1` in each iteration, i.e `n` is added to it when loop terminates.  So, `k = k + 1` is not equal to `k = k + k`.

Running time of the code is of order `n` because the loop runs `n` times and `++k` is done in constant time inside the loop.